# Post Image from Base64 (ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, base64, decode

I'm trying to use the following code in order to post the image result of a base64 canvas object captured in as a form field. Note that "sign" is the field that posts with the following result (no image conversion): "data: image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..."

I know that I need to remove the "data: image/png;base64," from the conversion, which is how I stumbled across the below code in the first place.

```
    dataurl = Request("sign")
    data = dataurl.Substring(dataurl.IndexOf(",") + 1)
    newsign = Convert.FromBase64String(data)
    Page.Canvas.DrawImage newsign, "x=216; y=705"
```

I get the following error:

> Object required: 'dataurl'

Can someone point me to where my syntax is wrong so I can get this working?

**UPDATE**
Okay - here's where I'm out now. But I'm getting an error "Object required: 'Convert'"

```
dataurl = Request("sign")
text = response.write(Mid(dataurl,23))
newsign = Convert.FromBase64String(text)
Page.Canvas.DrawImage newsign, "x=216; y=705"
```

In my head, I'm telling it to convert the output of the string starting at the 23rd character but obviously, the code doesn't agree with my thought process. I'm hoping this is something really easy to spot and fix. Thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Substring` or `IndexOf` in VBScript/Classic ASP.

You're either trying to use Javascript in Classic asp which is a bit different, or you need to use native VBScript functions for this.  Ie: `Instr()` and `Mid()`

---

Regards to your edit, there are certain things that can be done, and others that can't. Why? Because you need to use either VBScript or Javascript, not both. VBScript doesnt handle objects like Javascript, that's why you're getting the error.

If you would like to use server side Javascript in classic asp, have a look here: [Writing JavaScript in ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704736/writing-javascript-in-asp-classic)

**This might be your best bet considering your code is already in Javascript.**  You would test your original code, not your edit--Because your edit is completely invalid and worthless at this point.

However if you were to rewrite it in VBScript, there are certain changes you need to make:

```
dataurl = Request("sign")
data = Mid(dataurl,Instr(dataurl,",") + 1)
```

That's the easy part, now:

```
newsign = FromBase64String(data)
```

you can look here for pre-built code to build your function: http://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/

You would have to write this function yourself.

```
Set PageCanvasDrawImage = Server.CreateObject("YourObjectsName")
PageCanvasDrawImage newsign, "x=216; y=705" 
Set PageCanvasDrawImage = Nothing
```

First, you need to see if its packaged `.dll` register in your web server com+ object, then you can use it using `Server.CreateObject` once it's registered in the CLR (vbscript).  This is the tricky part, as ASP Classic isn't really supported, and Canvas is a newer technology. You'll have to see if the software provider supports .dll files like this, or go digging online for a component that supports it, or write one yourself.

Comment: thanks. You are correct - it's classic ASP. I apologize, but I'm a newbie to ASP...Can you elaborate on what I need to do to get this to work (i.e. convert the base64 string to an actual image?

Comment: Helps to search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629104/save-base64-to-an-image-using-classic-asp

Comment: ...please see my updates above and let me know your thoughts. I took your advise and used Mid() instead of Substring(), but now I'm getting a different error.

Comment: Did you view the link I posted?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I want to do. I don't want to save the image to the server. I just want to convert the base64 to bytes.

Comment: Have a look at `Adodb.Stream` for all of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry - you seem extremely knowledgeable, but I feel like I'm asking your opinion on the best possible car to buy and your pointing me to Kelly Bluebook's website. <br>Like I said, I'm new to  ASP. Can you help me understand why I'm getting the "Object Required: Convert" error?